# CoreData multithreading_violation debugging

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

We're using core data on multiple thread and am getting a multithreading_violation. usually it is pretty easy to fix, see where the violation is and make sure the code is executed within a performBlock call.

The issue today is that the call stack does not point to anything that give me much clue. I figure someone might have some insights on how to track this one down

```
#0  0x05e40f63 in +[NSManagedObjectContext __Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__] ()
#1  0x05e4138b in _PFAssertSafeMultiThreadedAccess_impl ()
#2  0x05e0c15d in -[_PFBatchFaultingArray dealloc] ()
#3  0x05e0c1dd in -[_PFBatchFaultingArray release] ()
#4  0x07130eb1 in objc_release ()
#5  0x07131d32 in (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) ()
#6  0x080d0536 in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#7  0x080d1b70 in _dispatch_worker_thread3 ()
#8  0x0842d1da in _pthread_wqthread ()
#9  0x0842ae2e in start_wqthread ()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and just noticed that the error doesn't appear when I don't fetch data in batches, i.e. don't set the fetchBatchSize on NSFetchRequest.

This is probably a bug in iOS 8.3 implementation of PFBatchFaultingArray.

Comment: Was experiencing the same with iOS12, removed `fetchBatchSize` and everything goes without exceptions. Curious, if its bug of multithreading_violation or `PFBatchFaultingArray`?